# Деепричастный оборот — обобление

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Нужно ли обособлять? Если что, деепричастный оборот — это суть в нижеуказанных предложениях.

---

`Как пройти Майнкрафт(,) не ломая блоки.`

`Я прошел Майнкрафт(,) не открывая двери.`

`Я прошел Майнкрафт(,) не сломав ни одного блока.`

`Я прошел Майнкрафт(,) ни одной двери не открыв.`

Answer (score 1):

Не обосабливается, [*если деепричастие тесно связано по смыслу со сказуемым и является главной информацией, которая сообщается.*](https://dzen.ru/a/WwU41nfQ5q3x7Y2Q)

-Что ты сделал? - Я прошел Maincraft. - **Как** ты его прошёл? - Я прошёл Maincraft не открывая двер**ей**.(двери - это одной двери)

Аналогично: Я прошёл Maincraft открывая двери. - "открывая двери" это **обязательное условие** прохождения.

Отрицание вообще не влияет на постановку запятой, однако, на обособление будет влияет расположение семантических блоков?

Отрывая двери, я прошёл Maincraft. - *я прошёл* никак не может быть условием к *открыванию дверей*, значит нужно поставить обособить инверсию, так как без обособления сказанное последним несёт основную смысловую нагрузку.

[**Правило у Розенталя**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%20%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5,%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82):

> Примечание. Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:\
>
> 1. если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства
>    образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует
>    смысловой центр высказывания: Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) —
>    указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой...

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149113/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.